# Write string with newlines to file

Tags: java, string, file, textarea, newline

I have a string that I get from a TextArea. This string includes user input newlines. I want to write the entire string (including those newlines) to a file.

This is what I have now:

```
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(nm + ".txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        pw.print(txt);
        pw.close();
```

I've googled but I have no clue as to how I could fix my problem.

Comment: This should work... Save for the fact that you don't specify your encoding when writing to the file. So, what is the problem exactly?

Comment: If I, say type 3 times "test" on a new line everytime and "save" the file in my application, when i open the file afterwards with notepad it it just says "testtesttest"

Comment: notepad can be confusing sometimes. `\r\n` issues in windows.

Comment: I see... Can you dump the chars of the string when you get it from your `TextArea`? Are the newlines `\n` or `\r\n`?

Comment: @SubirKumarSao unfortunately that doesn't seem to work

Comment: Is using a "real" text editor an option (notepad++ for instance)?

Comment: Use notepad ++ or other similar editors to actually see if you have `\n` or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See in this direction:

```
 1. System.getProperty("line.separator");
 2. System.lineSeparator();
```

For example:

```
pw.print(txt.replace("\n", System.lineSeparator()).replace("\r\n", System.lineSeparator()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have no problem with your code.

Anyway, if you use Java 7 you should use `Files`:

```
final Path path = Paths.get(nm + ".txt");

try (
    BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
        StandardOpenOption.APPEND, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
) {
    writer.write(txt);
    writer.flush();
}
```